# Suckers on dead ash tree

Tags: trees, suckers

My ash tree died from the ash borer, but there are suckers coming from the trunk---two questions:

1. should I cut the tree down?
2. can I keep the suckers and trim to become a tree?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and yes, but the borers will return for never having left. Your call.

[Darn the Emerald Ash Borer](https://blog.irontreeservice.com/invasive-insects-of-the-northeast-emerald-ash-borer/):

> Emerald ash borer feeds primarily on ash trees, including green,
> white, black, and blue ash. Infestations have also been reported in
> white fringetree. Emerald ash borer reproduces in trees of all sizes
> . . . **saplings** to fully mature trees.

[image: Emerald Ash Borer]